# How to skip blank cells when copying a range from source to destination by Formula

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have three levels of hierarchical data in Google Spreadsheets that looks something like this:

[image: Three level hierarchical data]

As data is being entered in here, I want it collect in three separate sheets like this:

[image: Level 1 Data] [image: Level 2 Data]

The solution I am looking for is a formula driven approach. I have tried VLOOKUP but can't seem to figure out how to make it work for this situation. I have googled quite a bit and all I am getting is applying filters, or removing blank cells like this [one](http://chandoo.org/wp/2010/01/26/delete-blank-rows-excel/), but that does not serve my purpose.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Filter() should do that. Let's say the sheet with the 'source data' is called Sheet1, then on the second sheet (where you want the level1 names), in cell A1 try:

```
=filter(Sheet1!A:A; len(Sheet1!A:A))
```

and repeat for all the other sheets and ranges..

Answer (score 3):

(if you still need that - probably is the simplest way would be:

```
UNIQUE(Sheet1!A:A)` or `SORT(Sheet1!A:A;condition)
```

;)

Comment: The problem that I've faced with UNIQUE is that it still filters in a blank row if there is one in the range. I find FILTER to work better.

Comment: @Allan agree, but probably bigger problem with UNIQUE() is that it filters all the same values and give you only 1 record in the separate sheet

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the [QUERY function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en).<sup>* see important notes</sup>

```
SYNTAX: QUERY(data, query, [headers])
```

For example:

```
=QUERY(A:A, "where A is not null", 0)
```

Equivalent variations (not exhaustive):

```
=QUERY(A:A, "select A where A is not null", 0)
=QUERY(A:A, "select * where A is not null", 0)
```

##### Specifying Columns (Index vs. Letter)

QUERY supports the following options for specifying columns.

1. **By Letter** - only supported where **`data`** is a range.
   Typically produces shorter and more readable formulas

   ```
   =QUERY(K:N, "select L")
   ```
2. **By Index** - This is supported for both ranges and arrays

   ```
   =QUERY(K:N, "select Col2")        //  Column L is INDEX(K:N,,2)
   =QUERY({K:L,M:N}, "select Col2")  //  Column L is INDEX({K:L,M:N},,2)
   ```

#### Arrays vs. Ranges

Because QUERY supports both arrays and ranges, you can combine ranges directly in the data argument.

The following example:

1. Creates an array for the **`data`** argument from Columns A to Z of three different sheets
2. Removes rows where Column A is empty
3. Includes the column labels `A1:Z1` from the first sheet only

   ```
    =QUERY(
       {March!A1:Z; April!A2:Z; June!A2:Z}, 
       "where Col1 is not null", 1)
   ```

- **`headers`** is set to **`1`** so QUERY doesn't see it as part of the data and allows further customization of the query statement such as sorting the data while leaving the heading at the top.
- You can learn more about the **`{}`** syntax for creating arrays [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en).

---

## Important Notes about Mixed Data

1. QUERY expects each column's data to contain either text strings or numbers, but not both.
2. QUERY will typically assign a column's data type based on which data type occurs in it more frequently (more values) or numbers.
3. Function syntax that may work for one data type may return an error or unexpected results.  FILTER is often used for mixed data, or incorporated into the QUERY to avoid issues.

### Mixed Data Examples:

#### Common Source Data

- used for all examples that follow
- assume that each column represents a different version of Column A.
- the operators are used to indicate the relative count in columns with mixed types ie. **`Text <= #`** means that for that column there are an equal or smaller number of cells containing text values as those containing numbers.

| All # | Text | Text <= # | Text > # |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  | 1 | 1 |  |
| 1 | one |  | one |  |
|  |  | one |  |  |
|  |  |  | two |  |

#### Example 1 (Formula and Results)

```
=QUERY(A:A, "where A != ''", 0)
```

| # | Text | Text <= # | Text > # |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| #N/A | one | #N/A | 1 | `←` **1** is no longer a # in **`Text > #`** results |
|  |  |  | one |  |
|  |  |  | two |  |

#### Example 2

```
=QUERY(A:A, "where A is not null", 0)
```

| # | Text | Text <= # | Text > # |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | one | 1 | 1 | `←` **1** is no longer a # in **`Text > #`** results |
|  |  |  | one |  |
|  |  |  | two |  |

#### Example 3

`=QUERY(A:A, "select SUM(A) label SUM(A) ''", 0)`

| # | Text | Text <= # | Text > # |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | #VALUE! | 1 | #VALUE! |  |

Comment: I edited your answer to correct some errors and add additional context and explanations.  I appreciate that it was a significant edit and if you are not okay with it don't hesitate to roll it back and I will add it as a separate answer.  Once you acknowledge this comment I will remove it.

Answer (score 1):

## [TOCOL Function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13187258?hl=en)

```
=TOCOL(Sheet1!A:A,1)
```

- May be the shortest approach.
- [TOCOL](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13187258?hl=en)  removes blanks when  **`ignore=1`**
- Added to Sheets Feb/2023.

## Syntax

```
=TOCOL(array_or_range,
       [ignore],
       [scan_by_col])
```

Comment: Thanks for a shorter and a more concise answer.

Answer (score -2):

```
=flatten(filter(A:A;not(isblank(A:A))))
```

or

```
=flatten(filter(A:A;len(A:A)))
```

or

```
=filter(flatten(A:A);len(flatten(A:A)))
```

Comment: This answer would be improved if you explained why you apply the [FLATTEN function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10307761?hl=en) to column A given that the function's sole purpose is to flatten multiple ranges into a single column which A:A is already. Otherwise, it seems to be a duplicate of the [accepted answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/72623).